# iOS game of drawing sticks with AI and scoring

Tags: beginner, game, swift, ios, ai

My code actually works. I was just wondering if there was alternative ways, maybe even more efficient ways of coding my program. This is suppose to be a game of drawing stick, and it's recording the score after each game. If I'm missing anything can someone let me know? Sort of new at this. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class PlayerVsPlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    var stats = GameStats.sharedStats
    var isPlayingAi = false
    var ai: SticksAi?

    @IBOutlet weak var Player2Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Player1Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SticksLeft: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SticksSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var PlayerWinsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerChoiceSticksLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnStartGame: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnStartNewGame: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblAiChoice: UILabel!

    var currentSticks = 0
    var sticksTaken = 0
    var p1Score = 0
    var p2Score = 0
    var whoWins = ""
    var isPlayerNumber = 1
    var originalSticksCount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblAiChoice.isHidden = true
        PlayerWinsLabel.text = whoWins
        btnStartNewGame.isHidden = true
        SticksLeft.text = String(55)
        Player1Score.text = String(p1Score)
        Player2Score.text = String(p2Score)
        SticksSlider.value = 55
        NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.isEnabled = false
        print("Am i playing against an AI: \(isPlayingAi)")

        if ai == nil {
            ai = SticksAi(withStickCount: currentSticks)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(_ slider: UISlider) {

        let value = lroundf(slider.value)
        currentSticks = value
        originalSticksCount = value
        if isPlayingAi {
            ai = SticksAi(withStickCount: currentSticks)
        }

        SticksLeft.text = String(currentSticks)

    }

    @IBAction func segmentSlected(_ segment: UISegmentedControl) {
            currentSticks -= segment.selectedSegmentIndex + 1
            segment.setEnabled(currentSticks >= 3, forSegmentAt: 2)
            segment.setEnabled(currentSticks >= 2, forSegmentAt: 1)
            SticksLeft.text = String(currentSticks)
            segment.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
            isPlayerNumber = isPlayerNumber == 1 ? 2 : 1
            if isPlayerNumber == 1 {
                playerChoiceSticksLabel.text = "Player 1: choose your sticks"
            } else {
                if isPlayingAi {
                    aiTurn()
                    if currentSticks > 0 {
                       isPlayerNumber = 1
                    }
                } else {
                    playerChoiceSticksLabel.text = "Player 2: choose your sticks"
                }
            }
            if currentSticks == 0 {
                NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.isEnabled = false
                if isPlayingAi && isPlayerNumber == 2 {
                    PlayerWinsLabel.text = "AI Wins!"
                } else {
                    PlayerWinsLabel.text = "Player \(isPlayerNumber) Wins!"
                }
                if isPlayerNumber == 1 {
                    p1Score += 1
                    stats.addGame(type: isPlayingAi ? .PlayerVsAi : .PlayerVsPlayer, won: true, sticks: originalSticksCount, playerMoves: 0, opponentMoves: 0)
                } else {
                    p2Score += 1
                    stats.addGame(type: isPlayingAi ? .PlayerVsAi : .PlayerVsPlayer, won: false, sticks: originalSticksCount, playerMoves: 0, opponentMoves: 0)
                }
                Player1Score.text = String(p1Score)
                Player2Score.text = String(p2Score)
                playerChoiceSticksLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startGame() {
        lblAiChoice.isHidden = true
        NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.isEnabled = true
        SticksSlider.isEnabled = false
        btnStartGame.isHidden = true
        btnStartNewGame.isHidden = false
        NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 2)
        NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
        isPlayerNumber = 1
        playerChoiceSticksLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func startNewGame() {
        lblAiChoice.isHidden = true
        btnStartNewGame.isHidden = true
        btnStartGame.isHidden = false
        SticksSlider.isEnabled = true
        NumberOfSticksSegmentCtrl.isEnabled = false
        SticksLeft.text = String(55)
        Player1Score.text = String(p1Score)
        Player2Score.text = String(p2Score)
        SticksSlider.value = 55
        currentSticks = Int(SticksLeft.text!)!
    }

    func aiTurn() {
        if isPlayerNumber == 2 && currentSticks > 0 {

            let aiMove = ai?.takeTurn(sticksLeft: currentSticks)
            currentSticks -= aiMove!
            SticksLeft.text = String(currentSticks)
            lblAiChoice.isHidden = false
            lblAiChoice.text = "AI has chosen \(aiMove!) sticks."
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBAction func closeGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: please: alsways lowercase the first letter if it is an instance of an class or an element. this helps do distinct it from a class and if you call a class method

Answer (score 1):

As @muescha mentions in the comment, variables should be lowercased. Here are a few other quick improvements I would suggest in the current code: the naming of the variable `isPlayerNumber` is rather misleading as conventions indicates this to be a `Bool` while it is in reality an Int. I've changed it to simply read `playerNumber` below:

I would also suggest simplifying the "choose your sticks" part of your segmentSelected function:

```
if isPlayingAi {
    aiTurn()
    if currentSticks > 0 {
        playerNumber = 1
    }
} else {
    playerChoiceSticksLabel.text = "Player \(playerNumber): choose your sticks"
}
```

There is some code duplication that can be avoided further down in the same function:

```
if isPlayerNumber == 1 {
    p1Score += 1
} else {
    p2Score += 1
}
stats.addGame(type: isPlayingAi ? .PlayerVsAi : .PlayerVsPlayer, won: false, sticks: originalSticksCount, playerMoves: 0, opponentMoves: 0)
```

I think I would rejig the `sticksLeft`-label and `currentSticks` logic as well. (Perhaps renaming the latter `stickCount` at the same time). Then rather than setting the `sticksLeft.text = ""` everywhere you could do:

```
var stickCount: Int {
    didSet {
        sticksLeft.text = "\(stickCount)"
    }
}
```

in its current scope I think you solution is generally fine, but if you plan to expand on this it might make sense to separate things further, perhaps having an array of `Player` structs rather than p1Score, p2Score, isPlayingAi etc. as well.